# How to located 'Fault Modules' cited by Reliability Monitor app

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

I provide remote online software support through which I've seen hundreds of user's Reliability History reports, showing varying degrees of "stability" on the graph. Some track really well, some are abysmal. The Reliability History on my own Windows laptop is among the worst I've seen despite the "Critical Events" not manifesting any noticeable issues (otherwise I would have addressed them).

Although these events do not manifest symptoms I'd like to investigate the "Fault Module" attributed to each event. (I'm aware that the 'fault modules' cited are not necessarily the cause of the event).

I'd like to locate both cited .dll files as well as 'StachHash____' items (whatever they are). I can search cited .dlls in the Program Folder, but any attempt to search the C:\Windows returns nothing and just gets stuck at about 97% complete.

I'm no software engineer, so go easy on any command line stuff!

**What's the best way to locate the files cited as the 'Fault Module'?**

EDIT: I now understand the cited 'Fault Module' lies within the 'Faulting Application Path' cited at the top of the 'Problem Details' view. (I had presumed this not to be the case). I'm still keen to hear what 'StackHash' refers to.

Comment: It is the hash of the stack. CPU store local variables, return memory address of the calling functions, parameters passed to functions on a stack. A hash is like a fingerprint. So it identifies other crashes of that specified function with the same data. Modules are where Windows API functions live. StackHash is for Microsoft's benefit so they can choose a customer (big customers) with the same problem as a lot of same errors  and debug one of them to fix all of them.

Comment: PS all Windows API DLLs are in C:\Windows\System32 directory for 64 bit programs and in C:\Windows\SysWoW64 for 32 bit programs. For most DLLs there will be one in each location. StackHashes are only useful for functions that don't take memory addresses.

Comment: There are two places programs stuff data. The heap which is where strings and global variables live. And the stack where memory relating to calling functions live. In a stack you push data onto the stack and then call a function. When the function returns the data is popped of the stack.

Comment: @user1292580 Thanks for such a big contribution! While I'm flattered you believe I'm experienced enough to understand all that, I have to admit I can't make complete sense of it. For me at least, such specialised concepts are better conveyed using analogies or metaphors. Maybe it will crystallise during sleep tonight… Thanks again!